# memorize the sum total of each key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this :

```
{1224:{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5}, 1225: {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 5}}
```

I want to store the total of A in each key and get a result like this :

```
{1224:{'A': 6, 'B': 4, 'C': 5, 'Total_A' : 6}, 1225: {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 5, 'Total_A' : 12}}
```

Total_A being the A value in first key (1224) + A value in next key (1225).

I tried this :

```
for d in celldict.values():
    sum = 0
    sum += d.get('A',0)
    d['TOTAL_A'] = sum
```

But it doesn't sum anything and it only returns the A value for each key every time.

Comment: Have you thought about what happens to `sum`?

Comment: Since the value of the dict is a `dict`, then what use is having `total_a`, when there's only at most one A anyway? Might as well just have `value['total_A'] = value.get('total_A', 0)` - which just reduces to `value.get('A', 0)` anyway...

Comment: @JonClements In the second dict, `total_a` is the sum of `a` in both dicts.

Comment: @phantom uh huh - that's made that slightly more clear - but I'm still curious as why the OP wants this...? This makes no sense as a maintainable data structure...

Comment: @JonClements No, it doesn't, but hasn't your stay on SO got you accustomed to all sorts of "interesting" requests?

Answer (score 7):

i think you should know what happened in the loop.
correct answer is follow:

```
sum = 0
for d in celldict.values():
    sum += d.get('A',0)
    d['TOTAL_A'] = sum
```

Comment: Jun, your version of the code was wrong. Martin probably thought you messed up with the indent... Anyway, I think this example shows why it's a bad idea to try to "fix" mistakes in someone else's codes by means of edits and not comments.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that you reset `sum` on each iteration. This is why `sum` never accumulates the previous values.

Move `sum = 0` outside the loop.

Comment: How could I have missed this? Thank you!